# Specify specific value in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How I can specify only `check` from data column in the plot.

**Data**

```
data           x-axis y-axis      result
abc                2    1         negative
abc                3    1         negative
check              1    1         positive
abc                4    1         positive
```

**Code**

```
 ax1=sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x-axis", y="y-axis", hue="result",markers= 'x',s=950,label=None,  )
    #ax1.set(xlabel=None, ylabel=None, xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])
    ax1.set_yticks((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), minor=0)
    ax1.set_xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], minor=False)
    #plt.legend(bboxche_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
    plt.setp(ax1.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='14') # for legend text
    ax1.plot()
```

**Plot**
[image]

Comment: Can you clariy your exact question?  How is the title related to the post?  You can use `sns.scatterplot(data=df[ df['data']=='check' ], ...)` to only show those rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['data']=='check'] use this to specify the data during  plotting
```